# Gradle building old version of code

Tags: java, gradle, build, windows-10, fatjar

I'm trying to build a fat jar with gradle but every time I do I get a really old version of the program. Running the program from main directly in IntelliJ works fine so it is something with the gradle build itself that is not working. When i check the jar in (project path)/build/libs the date and time of the file has changed so it did indeed build but when i start it i get a month old build. I suspect there might be some cache that is causing this but i do not know where that is located.

build.gradle

```
version '1.0.2'

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.Main',
        )
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.intellij:forms_rt:6.0.5'
    compile project(':common')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'example'

include ':common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../common')
```

Command

```
 ./gradlew fatjar
```

Comment: Even with the `clean` task ?

Comment: Yes I have tried both clean and deleting all tmp file manually. Either worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I discovered the problem and it was a combination of things. The only thing that was actually outdated was the form ui. The reason for this was that IntelliJ started using binary class files for the forms instead of java source files.

To fix it go to settings then editor and after that GUI designer. Press Java source code instead of binary class files. Regenerate the design (might have to delete the generated code and run it again). Then build it with gradle, it should now work.